# How to create topics in jaspersoft studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to use pre-defined sql queries in generating reports on JasperReports Server professional edition.

How can i create topics in jaspersoft studio designer in order to use pre-defined sql queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: create a report with out any design(ie add query and parameters) and save it in ireport.

step2:deploy report in server and add input controls to it.

step3:in server create adhocview by selecting topic then drag the columns.